# What does it mean that v8 compiles js code to native machine code?

Tags: v8, embedded-v8, libv8

How does v8 load and execute the native machine code it generates?

Answer (score 1):

Basically V8 creates a byte array containing the native instructions. It then copies the data into an executable memory region from which point on you can directly jump/call to it.

See [FinalizeCode](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/v8/src/compiler/code-generator.cc?l=355) within the compiler which sets up a new Code object.

As for calling, you'll find the detailed frame description in [frame-constants.h](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/v8/src/frame-constants.h?dr=CSs) where you want